# Is it possible to compare a string with all items of an array without a loop?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, compare

Is possible to use a built in function to compare a string with all values in an array?
Like so:

```vb
Dim NormalString as string = "Test"
Dim ArrayString = New String() {"Test", "Test2", "Test3"}

If NormalString = ArrayString.AllItems Then
    Debug.WriteLine("String found in Array")
End If
```

Or would I have to iterate through the strings in a loop and compare them one by one in a loop?

Note: I do understand that `ArrayString.AllItems` isn't a function that is available.

Comment: `ArrayString.Contains()` for equality or `ArrayString.Any()` + `IndexOf()` for partial matches.

Comment: Btw, you should define the criteria of the comparison and its desired result (e.g., a number of matches, bool when at least 1 matches, partial or complete match etc., since the method to apply is different. You may also need a custom comparer if the actual array doesn't exactly contain simple strings).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If ArrayString.Any(Function(s) s = NormalString) Then
```

You can call `Any` on any `IEnumerable(Of T)`, so any array, collection or LINQ query. Calling `Any` with no argument is equivalent to testing whether `Count` is greater than zero. With an argument, it will tell you whether any items in the list satisfy the specified criteria.

Comment: Super, this solved the problem. Would you care to explain the concept of how `(Function(s)`, it is rather new to me. If not, would you happen to know where I can read more about it?

Comment: That is the VB syntax for a Lambda Expression, which is a LINQ feature. You should be able to find what you need with those keywords. LINQ is a topic that you may like to look into in general. It stands for Language Integrated Query and allows you to do SQL-like queries on .NET lists. In essence, it specifically allows you to do things with each item in a list without a loop.

Comment: Isn't there a loop behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1):

For exact string:

```
Function ExistExactStringInArray(sourceArr() As String, searchedString As String, Optional ignoreCase As Boolean = True) As Boolean
    Return (From element As String In sourceArr
            Where CBool(If(ignoreCase, (
                 element?.Trim.ToLower = searchedString?.Trim.ToLower),
                (element = searchedString)))).Count > 0
End Function
```

For partial string:

```
Function ExistPartialStringInArray(sourceArr() As String, searchedString As String, Optional ignoreCase As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    Return (From element As String In sourceArr
            Where CBool(If(ignoreCase,
                            element?.Trim.ToLower.IndexOf(searchedString?.Trim.ToLower) > -1,
                            element.IndexOf(searchedString) > -1))).Count > 0
End Function
```

Comment: Don't call `ToList` and then use its `Count` property when you can just call `Count` on the query directly. If you don;t actually care what the count is, but only whether it is zero or not, then call `Any` rather than `Count`. Don't use that old VB6 `Trim` function when the `String` class has its own `Trim` method. Don't use `ToUpper` or `ToLower` for case-insensitive comparisons that don;t always work when methods like `String.Equals` and `String.IndexOf` have overloads that inherently allow for proper case-insensitivity.

Comment: Thanks for advices ;)

Comment: The first method body should be just this: `Return sourceArr.Any(Function(s) s.Equals(searchedString, If(ignoreCase, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)))`. The second should be just this: `Return sourceArr.Any(Function(s) s.IndexOf(searchedString, If(ignoreCase, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, StringComparison.CurrentCulture)) <> -1)`. Note that I have not done any trimming because what if you actually want to include a leading or trailing space?

Comment: @jmcilhinney At the exact moment I have 4 project opened in 2 different IDE’s with 3 different languages (not VBA, I hate it). So all you have wrote is not new for me, but as you now in quickly mode is possible your solution is not the best. So thanks again. Obviously your answer is better than my answer in this case.

Comment: Another thing is: I use a lot for convenience Trim (by old VBA, I know just a bit VBA) because I hate doing tests to a String before, if it is Nothing or not(.Tolower and IndexOf thrown me an exception in Nothing values). I hear you later in our journey :)

Comment: We all provide the best answers we can. If someone else knows something we don't and we can learn from them, all the better.

Comment: I'm totally  agree with you

Comment: If you are concerned about null references then use null propagation, e.g. use `myString?.Trim()` rather than `myString.Trim()`. The latter will throw an exception if `myString` is `Nothing` while the former will evaluate to `Nothing`.

Comment: Yeah. This seems interesting. Let me say  at this point that this is new for me.